# UTF-8 files read in python will line break at character \x85

Tags: python, file, readline

I had a problem where I had a playlist of songs that would not correctly linebreak when read using `codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf8')`. Every two lines in the playlist files contains the metadata in the first line, and the track filename on the second one.

The filenames were in unicode, and I encountered some track titles that had the \x85 character in the name due to bad tagging or character set mismatching. So there would be a metadata line like `'Title title \x85 title - artist`, and would incorrectly linebreak when the file was read using readline.

Comment: Did you check to see what the character with codepoint \x85 was?  See http://www.charbase.com/0085-unicode-next-line-nel

Comment: Yes, it's treated as a linebreak by standard, but I knew for a fact the files I was working with only needed \n

Comment: Related: Bug "codecs.open interprets space as line ends" http://bugs.python.org/issue18291

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Instead of calling `file.readline`, I would have a function that wraps readline. Originally I had it character by character which was slow, but then I forgot readline breaks prematurely and can be constructed into a correct line with further calls.

```
def getline(_file):
    ln = ''
    while True:
        _ln = _file.readline()
        ln += _ln
        if not _ln:
            break;
        if _ln[-1] == '\n':
            break
    return ln
```